# gradle fails to resolve .aar from artifactory

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, aar

I have a project that uses my own .aar library that is uploaded on artifactory.

The .pom file seems to be correct, as I have looked at other .aar libraries available on maven central. The .pom looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.modum</groupId>
  <artifactId>sweetblueservice</artifactId>
  <version>1.15</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
      <version>27.1.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support.constraint</groupId>
      <artifactId>constraint-layout</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.streamsupport</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-retrofuture</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jakewharton.timber</groupId>
      <artifactId>timber</artifactId>
      <version>4.7.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.10</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.modum</groupId>
      <artifactId>logger-utils</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.modum</groupId>
      <artifactId>sweetblue</artifactId>
      <version>2.52.16</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I install this library in my local maven repository on my machine, I am able to get the dependency in my Android project like this:

```
implementation "io.modum:sweetblueservice:1.15"
```

But somehow, this doesn't work when the library should be resolved from Artifactory:

```
    > Could not find sweetblueservice.jar (io.modum:sweetblueservice:1.15).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://modum.jfrog.io/modum/gradle-dev/io/modum/sweetblueservice/1.15/sweetblueservice-1.15.jar
```

Somehow

Comment: did you tried the extension property? implementation "io.modum:sweetblueservice:1.15@aar" for example

Comment: Yes, even with "transitive" set to true. It doesn't work, the dependencies are not resolved.

Comment: Does it still complain not finding the jar instead of aar?

Comment: happens the same to me, always looking for jar instead of aar. Any updates on this?

Comment: Did you every figure this out? I know it is over 2 years, but I'm seeing the same issue with Gradle 7 and Nexus